# Linq 2 Sql - Getting the Id of the newly inserted row - Not working?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Lets assume this code:

```
Classified classified = new Classified();
classified.Title = title;
classified.IsActive = true;

user.Classifieds.Add(classified);

dContext.SubmitChanges();

Response.Redirect(string.Format("/classifieds/post/?cid=", classified.Id));
```

Well, `classifiedId` has no value, Since i am redirected to `http://www.mysite.loc/classifieds/post/?cid=`

anyone?

Comment: Is `Id` the primary key and auto incrementing in the database?

Comment: Yes it is. cant understand why its happening.

Comment: Maybe try [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) instead of Add()?

Comment: @nkvu, Tried that also, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your string format:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("/classifieds/post/?cid={0}", classified.Id));
```

You forgot to include the `{0}` so it knows where to place the ID.

Comment: Cant believe i missed that. too many working hours, gonna go to the pool to relax, will accept in 9 minuets.

Comment: Wish I had a pool to relax in. Glad I could help!